# SQL SERVER - Tricky Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to rack my brain for a while, lots of Googling, but to no avail. I have a data set that has the following fields I need to query: `DEPT,NUM,TERM,ITLE`. I have the following possible rows.

```
DEPT--NUM---TERM------TITLE
OSS - 1550 - 200830 - COURSE NAME (CI)
OSS - 1550 - 200930 - COURSE NAME (CI)
OSS - 1550 - 201230 - COURSE NAME
ENG - 1600 - 200930 - OTHER COURSE (CI)
OSS - 1600 - 200830 - ANOTHER COURSE (CI)
USS - 2500 - 201240 - COURSE (CI)
PSY - 1600 - 200830 - COURSE TITLE
```

What I need to do is query a table with data such as this and then pull the `DEPT/NUM` (OSS 1550) where the title matches a query ONLY IF it's the latest title.

So if I do a search for (CI) I want 3 results using the set above (ENG 1600, OSS 1600, ISS 2500), because 201230 is the latest entry for OSS 1550 I don't want that one, but I do want the others. Right now I cannot for the life of me figure out how to write a query that will do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I am not clear enough.

EDIT

I am only getting a single record, here is what I am using based on what you have said
    SELECT data.*
    FROM (
        SELECT SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE || ' ' || SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB AS crs_combo,
        SCBCRSE_TITLE as title,
        row_number() over (ORDER BY SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM DESC, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB DESC) as term
        FROM        SCBCRSE 
        WHERE       (SCBCRSE_TITLE LIKE '%' || :srch || '%')
    ) data
    WHERE data.term = 1

My formatting is now working... no idea why I have four spaces.

EDIT AGAIN
I guess I didn't provide enough sample data... see edited table above. I need the three records with unique DEPT/NUM and the CI in the title, but not the one with older titles and CI. Make sense.

Sorry for not being clear.

ANSWER... here is the winner.

```
SELECT data.*
FROM (
    SELECT SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE || ' ' || SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB AS crs_combo,
    SCBCRSE_TITLE as title,
    row_number() over (partition by SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE,SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB ORDER BY SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM DESC) as seqnum
    FROM SCBCRSE 
) data
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND title LIKE '%' || :srch || '%'
```

Thanks for your help everyone. I wasted hours on this and you answered it in minuets.

Comment: do you have a primary key to this table? please give a more informative context, so that you can have a more specific answer

Comment: It sounds like you want the latest course that matches the title. I could also imagine that you want all courses that match the title, but only those where the "term" is the latest for the course.  Please clarify!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with ranking functions.  But, as I read the question, it is not as clear as I originally thought.  The following gets the latest course that matches the title:

```
select t.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by term desc, num desc) as seqnum
      from data d
      where title like '%(CI)%'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This assumes you are using version 2005 or greater.

If you are trying to find out all the "last" classes that match, then you can try:

```
select t.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by num order by term desc) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and title like '%(CI)%'
```

This returns any case where the last class (based on num, order by term) matches the "(CI)".  This is the other interpretation I had for your question.

Comment: Shouldn't I order by Term DESC? Thanks for the ultra fast reply. I may have edited why you were answering.

Comment: @user1229594 . . . I edited this several times in quick succession as I re-read your question and realized that perhaps I didn't fully understand it.

Comment: I am only getting a single record.

Comment: @user1229594 you only asked for a single record. Next time you ask a question, I surgest you include expected output

Comment: I need all records that match. In my example I only had 1 result because there was only 1 match. If there were 50 courses with different DEPT/NUMS that have CI in the title, I want those too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you add a partition by DEPT, NUM I think you would have what he needs

Comment: When I run your query with the seqnum = 1 I only get one result... I need all results from the inner query that have (CI) in them. I ran the inner query by itself and it is pulling only the correct titles. So I know the inner one is right. I could do a QoQ in CF at this point, but doing it in a single query would be best.

Comment: I feel stupid.  I left outer the "partition" part in the subquery, because I didn't not need it for the first query.  That is fixed.

Comment: Hey... thanks for your help. I wasted so much time on this this morning, and I knew there was an aggregate way to do it, but I am more of a programmer/front-end not DB SQL.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you only want to search the books from the `MAX(TERM)`, in which case this would work

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Books') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Books
CREATE TABLE #Books
(
    DEPT VARCHAR(5),
    NUM VARCHAR(10),
    TERM VARCHAR(10),
    TITLE VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #BOOKS (DEPT, NUM, TERM, TITLE) VALUES('OSS','1550','200830','COURSE NAME (CI)')
INSERT INTO #BOOKS (DEPT, NUM, TERM, TITLE) VALUES('OSS','1550','200930','COURSE NAME (CI)')
INSERT INTO #BOOKS (DEPT, NUM, TERM, TITLE) VALUES('OSS','1550','201230','COURSE NAME')
INSERT INTO #BOOKS (DEPT, NUM, TERM, TITLE) VALUES('ENG','1600','200930','OTHER COURSE (CI)')

SELECT b.*
FROM #Books b
JOIN (
    --Find the latest TERM
    SELECT
        DEPT, NUM, MAX(TERM) as TERM
    FROM #Books
    GROUP BY DEPT, NUM
    ) t
    ON b.DEPT = t.DEPT
    AND b.NUM = t.NUM
    AND b.TERM = t.TERM
WHERE TITLE LIKE ('%(CI)%')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c589/7):

```
;with a as 
(
  select * from 
  (
    select t.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by DEPT,NUM order by TERM DESC) row from t
  ) b 
  where row=1

)
select * from a where TITLE like '%(CI)%';
```